# How to find conflicts in LALR parser?

Tags: formal-grammars, parsers, lr-k

I have a LR analyser and I can't find out how to know whether the grammar is or is not LALR(1).

I think that I have to merge states with the same rules. So I have to merge states: $2 - 12, 3 - 13, 4 - 15, 7 - 9 -17, 8 - 16, 10 - 18 $

I think that LALR conflict is for example if I merge $ 2 - 12$ because in the rules $A -> .bS$ there are the same contexts $b$. Is it true? What should I do to know whether is there a LALR conflict? And LR conflicts?

[image]